# engine.muteLocalAudioStream(true), it doesn't work. (Agora)(Java)

Tags: java, sdk

When reading an audio file and sending audio data using `engine.pushExternalAudioFrame(...)`, audio is played from the speaker.

What should I do to prevent sound from the speaker at this time?

Even if you use `engine.muteLocalAudioStream(true)`, it doesn't work.